# MVC route not kept on RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got this route configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "routeB",
           "routeB/{action}/{id}",
           new { controller = "Sample", action = "IndexB", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(
           "routeA",
           "routeA/{action}/{id}",
           new { controller = "Sample", action = "IndexA", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And my Sample controller contains these Action methods:

```
 public ActionResult IndexA(string id)
    {

        return View("Index");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult IndexA()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Confirmation");
    }

    public ActionResult Confirmation()
    {
        return View("Confirmation");
    }

    public ActionResult IndexB(string id)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult IndexB()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Confirmation");
    }
```

If I land on the localhost/RouteA page and make a POST (via a button) it redirects me to localhost/RouteB/Confirmation.

How can I get the page to redirect to the RouteA/Confirmation page?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the view `Index`

Comment: The View Index can be found below:

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.Partial("OrderForm")

Comment: And the OrderForm:

    using (Html.BeginForm("IndexB", "Sample", new { @id = "OrderForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <button type="submit" id="orderFormBtn">Extend my discount.</button>   
}

Comment: Yes, that solves this scenario but I want it to work in both ways. If I type RouteB and make a POST it would go to RouteA/Confirmation in that case. I want to keep the same route all the time, no matter which one is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues here. As others have pointed out, your HTTP POST needs to be corrected. Since you are sharing a single view for 2 different actions, the simplest way to do that is to set the `actionName` parameter to `null`. This tells MVC to use the action name from the current request.

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, "Sample", new { id = "OrderForm" }))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="submit" id="orderFormBtn">Extend my discount.</button>
}
```

The second issue is that the `RedirectToAction` call is ambiguous between `routeA` and `routeB` when generating the URL. Since the first match always wins, the URL you are redirecting to is always the top one in your configuration.

You can fix this problem by using `RedirectToRoute` to specify the route name (in addition to your existing matching criteria) explicitly.

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult IndexA(string id)
    {

        return View("Index");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult IndexA()
    {
        return RedirectToRoute("routeA", new { action = "Confirmation" });
    }

    public ActionResult Confirmation()
    {
        return View("Confirmation");
    }

    public ActionResult IndexB(string id)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult IndexB()
    {
        // Note that changing this one to RedirectToRoute is not strictly
        // necessary, but may be more clear to future analysis of the configuration.
        return RedirectToRoute("routeB", new { action = "Confirmation" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks NighOwl888, this has solved the issue. This will help me in avoding to create 7 different controllers to display similar views :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite simple.
Take a look to your controller, the methods IndexA and IndexB, returns the same view; (from your comments)

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; } 

<h2>Index</h2>

using (Html.BeginForm("IndexB", "Sample", new { @id = "OrderForm" })) { 

@Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
<button type="submit" id="orderFormBtn">Extend my discount.</button> 
}
```

When you click on submit, you always do a post to `IndexB`

There are a lot of ways to correct such a simple error, for example you simple could use 2 different views `IndexA` and `IndexB` and change

`using (Html.BeginForm("IndexB", "Sample", new { @id = "OrderForm" })) {`

to

`using (Html.BeginForm("IndexA", "Sample", new { @id = "OrderForm" })) {`

Comment: The same happens if I change to using 

       (Html.BeginForm("IndexA", "Sample", new { @id = "OrderForm" }))

The page still redirects to RouteB/Confirmation.
Is there a way to keep the same Index View?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both your `routeA` and `routeB` routes will work for creating a link for an `IndexA` action in `SampleController`. As a result, `BeginForm` will just short-circuit and pick the first route that will work, which may or may not be the "correct" one you're looking for. To differentiate the routes, generate them via the route name:

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("routeA", new { @id = "OrderForm" })) {
```

However, that will only ever let you get the "default" `routeA` route, i.e. `/routeA/`. There's no way to specify a different action other than the default one for the route.

For more flexibility, you can employ attribute routing, which will allow you to give a custom route name to each action, which you can then use to get the URL for that action.

Short of that, you will need to differentiate the two routes in some way, so that it's not ambiguous which should be used when generating a URL. That's often difficult to do with standard routing, which is why attribute routing is the much better approach if you're going to diverge from simply using the default route for everything.

Alternatively, you can restructure your project to keep the same URL structure, but make it much easier to differentiate routes. By employing areas, you can then specify the area where the route should be created from. For example, assuming you had `RouteA` and `RouteB` areas, you could then do:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("IndexB", "Sample", new { area = "RouteA", @id = "OrderForm" })) {
```

That would then mean having a `SampleController` in each area, but you can employ inheritance to reuse code.